# How Can I Cascade Radio Buttons In Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to programming and am tasked with creating a clickable tournament bracket. 8 teams, where you can pick the winners who will advance to the next round.

The problem I'm running into is when a person would want to revise picks in the first or second round after filling out the bracket.

For example in the first round the user picks:

- Team1 v. Team8 --> #1 moves on
- Team4 v. Team5 --> #4 moves on
- Team3 v. Team6 --> #3 moves on
- Team2 v. Team7 --> #2 moves on

In the Second Round let's say they pick:

- Team1 v. Team4 --> #1 moves on
- Team2 v. Team3 --> #2 moves on

In the Finals, they pick:

- Team1 v. Team2 --> #1 wins.

Then, let's say the user changes their mind and picks Team8 to upset Team1 in the first round. Right now the code would still show Team1 as the winner and in the final game. How can I remove the text for the future rounds that currently shows Team1?

Attaching JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/a4hya2c7/5/ or see below code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Button</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>First Round</p>
      <div id="round1">
         <input type="radio" name="g1" id="i1" value="#1" onclick="changeText(this.value);"><label id="r1">#1</label>
         <input type="radio" name="g1" id="i2" value="#8" onclick="changeText(this.value);"><label id="r2">#8</label></br>
         <input type="radio" name="g2" id="i3" value="#4" onclick="changeText2(this.value);"><label id="r3">#4</label>
         <input type="radio" name="g2" id="i4" value="#5" onclick="changeText2(this.value);"><label id="r4">#5</label></br>
         <input type="radio" name="g3" id="i5" value="#3" onclick="changeText3(this.value);"><label id="r5">#3</label>
         <input type="radio" name="g3" id="i6" value="#6" onclick="changeText3(this.value);"><label id="r6">#6</label></br>
         <input type="radio" name="g4" id="i7" value="#7" onclick="changeText4(this.value);"><label id="r7">#7</label>
         <input type="radio" name="g4" id="i8" value="#2" onclick="changeText4(this.value);"><label id="r8">#2</label></br>
      </div>
      </br>
      <p>Second Round</p>
      <div id="round2">
         <input type="radio" name="g5" id="i9" onclick="changeText5(this.value);"><label id="r9"></label>
         <input type="radio" name="g5" id="i10" onclick="changeText5(this.value);"><label id="r10"></label></br>
         <input type="radio" name="g6" id="i11" onclick="changeText6(this.value);"><label id="r11"></label>
         <input type="radio" name="g6" id="i12" onclick="changeText6(this.value);"><label id="r12"></label></br>
      </div>
      </br>
      <p>Finals</p>
      <div id="round3">
         <input type="radio" name="g7" id="i13" onclick="changeText7(this.value);"><label id="r13"></label>
         <input type="radio" name="g7" id="i14" onclick="changeText7(this.value);"><label id="r14"></label></br>
      </div>
      </br>
      <p>Winner</p>
      <div id="round4">
         <label value="#8" id="r15"></label></br>
      </div>
      </br>
   </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
function changeText(value) {
    document.getElementById('r9').innerHTML = value;
    document.getElementById('i9').value = value;
}

function changeText2(value) {
    document.getElementById('r10').innerHTML = value;
    document.getElementById('i10').value = value;
}

function changeText3(value) {
    document.getElementById('r11').innerHTML = value;
    document.getElementById('i11').value = value;
}

function changeText4(value) {
    document.getElementById('r12').innerHTML = value;
    document.getElementById('i12').value = value;
}

function changeText5(value) {
    document.getElementById('r13').innerHTML = value;
    document.getElementById('i13').value = value;
}

function changeText6(value) {
    document.getElementById('r14').innerHTML = value;
    document.getElementById('i14').value = value;
}
function changeText7(value) {
    document.getElementById('r15').innerHTML = value;
    document.getElementById('r15').value = value;
}
```

Comment: You definitely want to use arrays, instead of repeating the same code a million times

Comment: @Isac I was thinking there would probably be a better way than repeating myself. I am literally just picking JS up on the fly. Could you provide an example of how I could do it in an array?

Comment: As far as simplifying the code, perhaps have the ids as parameters instead of hard coding. Then you can have just one function instead of 7 or howevermany you have. Like changeText (value, 'r14', 'i14')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly your `<br>` tags aren't correct as you can see here:

```
</div>
</br>
```

You are using the close tag without the opening. You can either use:

```
<br/>
```

Or use the newer html5 self closing tags style:

```
<br>
```

As to the JS itself, you can simplify it a lot if you use an attribute, similar as the `name` you are already using to point where it must put the value. With that change the code would be a lot smaller and simpler:

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]"); 

for (let inp of inputs){
  inp.addEventListener("change", function(){
    let targetLabel = document.getElementById(inp.dataset.target);    
    targetLabel.previousSibling.value = inp.value;
    targetLabel.innerHTML = inp.value;    
  });
}
```

```html
<p>First Round</p>
      <div id="round1">
         <input type="radio" name="g1" id="i1" value="#1" data-target="r9"><label id="r1">#1</label>
         <input type="radio" name="g1" id="i2" value="#8" data-target="r9"><label id="r2">#8</label><br>
         <input type="radio" name="g2" id="i3" value="#4" data-target="r10"><label id="r3">#4</label>
         <input type="radio" name="g2" id="i4" value="#5" data-target="r10"><label id="r4">#5</label><br>
         <input type="radio" name="g3" id="i5" value="#3" data-target="r11"><label id="r5">#3</label>
         <input type="radio" name="g3" id="i6" value="#6" data-target="r11"><label id="r6">#6</label><br>
         <input type="radio" name="g4" id="i7" value="#7" data-target="r12"><label id="r7">#7</label>
         <input type="radio" name="g4" id="i8" value="#2" data-target="r12"><label id="r8">#2</label><br>
      </div>
      <br>
      <p>Second Round</p>
      <div id="round2">
         <input type="radio" name="g5" id="i9" data-target="r13"><label id="r9"></label>
         <input type="radio" name="g5" id="i10" data-target="r13"><label id="r10"></label><br>
         <input type="radio" name="g6" id="i11" data-target="r14"><label id="r11"></label>
         <input type="radio" name="g6" id="i12" data-target="r14"><label id="r12"></label><br>
      </div>
      <br>
      <p>Finals</p>
      <div id="round3">
         <input type="radio" name="g7" id="i13" data-target="r15"><label id="r13"></label>
         <input type="radio" name="g7" id="i14" data-target="r15"><label id="r14"></label><br>
      </div>
      <br>
      <p>Winner</p>
      <div id="round4">
         <label value="#8" id="r15"></label><br>
      </div>
      <br>
```

Note that the targets i set were directly to the labels:

```
<input type="radio" ... data-target="r9">
```

Then to get to the corresponding radio i used [`previousSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/previousSibling).

I used several functions that you may not know:

- [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) - to get an array of elements matching the selector passed
- [`for ... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) to iterate on all inputs retrieved by the `querySelectorAll`
- [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) - to set the event handler directly on Javascript and make the code cleaner

And with just those little lines of Javascript you have the same functionality, and most importantly, without code duplication.

Now if you want to cascade a change on the first radios to the lower ones, you can call the change event directly with:

```
const event = new Event('change');
element.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Whenever you see that the target element already has a value set. This works like a recursive call:

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]"); 

for (let inp of inputs){
  inp.addEventListener("change", function(){
    let targetLabel = document.getElementById(inp.dataset.target);
    let targetRadio = targetLabel.previousSibling;
    targetRadio.value = inp.value;
    targetLabel.innerHTML = inp.value;
 
    //if this isn't the last and it's checked, to not cascade non selected radios
    if (targetRadio.hasAttribute && targetRadio.checked){ 
      const nextTargetLabel = document.getElementById(targetRadio.dataset.target);

      if (nextTargetLabel.innerHTML != ''){ //if it has a value then cascade
          targetRadio.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<p>First Round</p>
      <div id="round1">
         <input type="radio" name="g1" id="i1" value="#1" data-target="r9"><label id="r1">#1</label>
         <input type="radio" name="g1" id="i2" value="#8" data-target="r9"><label id="r2">#8</label><br>
         <input type="radio" name="g2" id="i3" value="#4" data-target="r10"><label id="r3">#4</label>
         <input type="radio" name="g2" id="i4" value="#5" data-target="r10"><label id="r4">#5</label><br>
         <input type="radio" name="g3" id="i5" value="#3" data-target="r11"><label id="r5">#3</label>
         <input type="radio" name="g3" id="i6" value="#6" data-target="r11"><label id="r6">#6</label><br>
         <input type="radio" name="g4" id="i7" value="#7" data-target="r12"><label id="r7">#7</label>
         <input type="radio" name="g4" id="i8" value="#2" data-target="r12"><label id="r8">#2</label><br>
      </div>
      <br>
      <p>Second Round</p>
      <div id="round2">
         <input type="radio" name="g5" id="i9" data-target="r13"><label id="r9"></label>
         <input type="radio" name="g5" id="i10" data-target="r13"><label id="r10"></label><br>
         <input type="radio" name="g6" id="i11" data-target="r14"><label id="r11"></label>
         <input type="radio" name="g6" id="i12" data-target="r14"><label id="r12"></label><br>
      </div>
      <br>
      <p>Finals</p>
      <div id="round3">
         <input type="radio" name="g7" id="i13" data-target="r15"><label id="r13"></label>
         <input type="radio" name="g7" id="i14" data-target="r15"><label id="r14"></label><br>
      </div>
      <br>
      <p>Winner</p>
      <div id="round4">
         <label value="#8" id="r15"></label><br>
      </div>
      <br>
```

**Edit**:

To clear the following radios instead of cascading the values you can use a `while`, and navigating with the `targets` until you reach the end:

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio]"); 

for (let inp of inputs){
  inp.addEventListener("change", function(){
    let targetLabel = document.getElementById(inp.dataset.target);
    let targetRadio = targetLabel.previousSibling;
    targetLabel.innerHTML = inp.value;
    targetRadio.value = inp.value;

     //while there is a next target clear it
    while (targetLabel.previousSibling.hasAttribute){
      targetLabel = document.getElementById(targetRadio.dataset.target);
      targetRadio = targetLabel.previousSibling;
      targetRadio.checked = false;
      targetLabel.innerHTML = '';
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<p>First Round</p>
      <div id="round1">
         <input type="radio" name="g1" id="i1" value="#1" data-target="r9"><label id="r1">#1</label>
         <input type="radio" name="g1" id="i2" value="#8" data-target="r9"><label id="r2">#8</label><br>
         <input type="radio" name="g2" id="i3" value="#4" data-target="r10"><label id="r3">#4</label>
         <input type="radio" name="g2" id="i4" value="#5" data-target="r10"><label id="r4">#5</label><br>
         <input type="radio" name="g3" id="i5" value="#3" data-target="r11"><label id="r5">#3</label>
         <input type="radio" name="g3" id="i6" value="#6" data-target="r11"><label id="r6">#6</label><br>
         <input type="radio" name="g4" id="i7" value="#7" data-target="r12"><label id="r7">#7</label>
         <input type="radio" name="g4" id="i8" value="#2" data-target="r12"><label id="r8">#2</label><br>
      </div>
      <br>
      <p>Second Round</p>
      <div id="round2">
         <input type="radio" name="g5" id="i9" data-target="r13"><label id="r9"></label>
         <input type="radio" name="g5" id="i10" data-target="r13"><label id="r10"></label><br>
         <input type="radio" name="g6" id="i11" data-target="r14"><label id="r11"></label>
         <input type="radio" name="g6" id="i12" data-target="r14"><label id="r12"></label><br>
      </div>
      <br>
      <p>Finals</p>
      <div id="round3">
         <input type="radio" name="g7" id="i13" data-target="r15"><label id="r13"></label>
         <input type="radio" name="g7" id="i14" data-target="r15"><label id="r14"></label><br>
      </div>
      <br>
      <p>Winner</p>
      <div id="round4">
         <label value="#8" id="r15"></label><br>
      </div>
      <br>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. That really helps a ton. Just for follow-up, for changes in an earlier round, instead of cascading to future rounds, is it possible to make all future instances of that number be blank instead?

Comment: @kbjw17 Yes there is, i have updated my answer to contemplate that scenario as well.

Comment: that is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Note that while this may work, the HTML is invalid. `target` is an invalid attribute for `input` tags. Use a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) instead: `data-target`

Comment: @JonP Thanks for the noticing that. I already updated it to `data-target`.